# How to add src into the iframe after clicking on the button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a link from data-embed into iframe as an src but it's not working. Please help me I'm new to jQuery. Here is my code;

```js
function initPlaylist() {

  const videoIframe = document.querySelector('#iframe-embed');

  const videoItems = document.querySelectorAll('.vid-item');

  videoIframe.src = window.atob(videoItems[0].getAttribute('data-embed'));

  for (var i = 0; i < videoItems.length; i++) {

    videoItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {

      videoIframe.src = window.atob(event.target.getAttribute('data-embed'));

      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

    });

    $(videoItems).first().addClass('selected');

  }

}(jQuery);
```

```html
<div id="player-wrap">
  <div class="responsive-vid">
    <iframe allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="350px" id="iframe-embed" width="100%" target="_blank"></iframe>
    <div class="playlist-wrap">
      <div class="video-list">
        <a class="vid-item" data-embed="https://asianhdplay.net/streaming.php?id=MzU1ODc0&title=Miracle+of+Love+%282022%29+episode+17&typesub=SUB">Episode 01</a>

        <a class="vid-item" data-embed="https://asianhdplay.net/streaming.php?id=MzU1ODc0&title=Miracle+of+Love+%282022%29+episode+17&typesub=SUB">Episode 02</a>

        <a class="vid-item" data-embed="https://asianhdplay.net/streaming.php?id=MzU1ODc0&title=Miracle+of+Love+%282022%29+episode+17&typesub=SUB">Episode 03</a>

        <a class="vid-item" data-embed="https://asianhdplay.net/streaming.php?id=MzU1ODc0&title=Miracle+of+Love+%282022%29+episode+17&typesub=SUB">Episode 04</a>

        <a class="vid-item" data-embed="https://asianhdplay.net/streaming.php?id=MzU1ODc0&title5=Miracle+of+Love+%282022%29+episode+17&typesub=SUB">Episode 05</a>

        <a class="vid-item" data-embed="https://asianhdplay.net/streaming.php?id=MzU1ODc0&title=Miracle+of+Love+%282022%29+episode+17&typesub=SUB">Episode 06</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ufr1.jpg)

Comment: Why are you trying to use `atob` on those values? `atob` decodes a base64-encoded value - which you don't have here.

Comment: Quite nonsensical to try and do this via JavaScript in the first place. The `target` attribute for links exists. So if your give your iframe a `name`, use that as `target` on your links and make them have an actual `href` instead of `data-href` - then you don't need JS to change the iframe source.

Comment: Your function should look more like `(function initPlaylist($) { /* code */ }(jQuery));` and not sure why you are using `window.atob` since you are not encoded.

Comment: Then what should I use instead of windows.atob?

Comment: well nothing since it is not encoded

Comment: I'm using atob because data-embed is like this: data-embed="aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cub25nZXR2aWRlby54eXovcGxheWhscy9wbGF5LnBocD9pZD0xMjk5NA==".  But whenever I'm trying to use https links it's not working. Even if I use windows.open instead of windows.atob

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
        $(".vid-item").on('click', function() {
            $("#iframe-embed").attr('src', $(this).attr('data-embed'));

            //or 
            $("#iframe-embed").attr('src', $(this).data('embed'));

            //or
            $("#iframe-embed").prop('src', $(this).prop('data-embed'));
        })
```